# Creating multiple radio buttons with *ngFor

Tags: html, angular, radio-button, angular8, angular-ngmodel

i created a task form with a response, reply and status using ngfor. loading responses and giving reply to reponse using input text and status are in radio button. they appear fine, but clicking any of them the last one is selected

```
  <div *ngFor="let data of task;let i = index;">
        <div>{{data.task}}</div>
      </div>
      <div class="task-reply">
          <textarea class="form-control" id="" cols="30" rows="3" placeholder="Response .."  [(ngModel)]="respo[i]"></textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="task-status">                 
        <input type="radio" name="work_status" class="select" [(ngModel)]="status[i]" value="finished" > Finished <br>
        <input type="radio" name="work_status" class="select" [(ngModel)]="status[i]" value="partially_completed"> Partially Completed <br>
        <input type="radio" name="work_status" class="select" [(ngModel)]="status[i]" value="started"> Started<br>
        <input type="radio" name="work_status" class="select" [(ngModel)]="status[i]" value="not_started"> Not Started      <br>
      </div>
      <div class="task-submit"> 
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Submit" id={{data.id}} (click)="onSubmit(data,respo[i],status[i])">
      </div>
      </div>
```

please help me to solve this problem.. thank you in advance

Comment: you need give different name in each iteration of task, some like `[name]="'work_status'+i"`

Comment: there is no change

Comment: the ngModel might be the issue, you are basically selecting the same model in all the radiobuttons